# Is there a way to retrieve Win32_Printjob info only when it has completed after successsfull printing?

Tags: c#, wmi

Currently I catch the event when a user prints but all the info is there, but TotalPages isn't accurate. The document will be 28 pages but it will only show 10 since the print job is still in the process.

I've tried looping in a while loop, but this just returned the same result everytime. Tried getting "Select * from Win32_PrintJob where JobId = N"

```
private void StartWatcher()
        {
            try
            {
                txtBox.Text += "\r\nMonitoring for printer activity...";
                string wqlQuery = @"Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 1
                    Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PrintJob'";

                Classes.Printer.clsPrinter clsPrinter = new Classes.Printer.clsPrinter();
                WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery(wqlQuery);
                ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
                watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(printJobArrived_EventArrived);
                watcher.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("Form1 StartWatcher: " + ex.Message.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

void printJobArrived_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                string note = "";


                ManagementBaseObject printJob = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value;
                note = "";
                note = "\r\n\r\nDescription :" + printJob.GetPropertyValue("Description").ToString();
                note += "\r\nTotal Pages:" + printJob.GetPropertyValue("TotalPages").ToString();
                //GetDetails(Convert.ToInt32(printJob.GetPropertyValue("JobId")));
                Upload(printJob.GetPropertyValue("TotalPages").ToString(), printJob.GetPropertyValue("Description").ToString());

                //foreach (PropertyData prop in printJob.Properties)
                //{
                //    string val = prop.Value == null ? "null" : prop.Value.ToString();
                //    note += "\r\n" + "\r\n" + prop.Name + ": " + val;
                //}

                txtBox.Invoke((Action)delegate
                {
                    txtBox.Text += note;
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("Form1 printJobArrived_EventArrived: " + ex.Message.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

The expected result is that it should return accurate number of Totalpages but it returns inaccurate values. Tested with print to pdf

Comment: 'Classes.Printer.clsPrinter' getting Classes could not found error

Answer (score 0):

So after searching, I've found the answer. The main issue was the query the event fired on its changed from

```
string wqlQuery = @"Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 1
                Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PrintJob'";
```

to

```
string wqlQuery = @"Select * From __InstanceModificationEvent  Within 0.1
                Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PrintJob' And TargetInstance.JobStatus = 'Printing'";
```